# Will CDN affect my SEO?

Tags: seo, cdn

I'm planning to use a CDN for hosting all my website files. This is because it makes the site load faster. My boss asked me a question before implementing this. Will this affect the SEO in any way. My first thought was No. But i'm still uncertain. Lets say my websites images appear in google images results. What will be the source? The cdn's url ? or my websites's ?

I'd like to know.

Comment: CDN's only change the IP address of your site via DNS to point to regional node servers, they do not change domain names or URLs, so neither users nor search engines will see any difference. Load times should decrease since the servers are closer to your visitors geographically and employ caching, thus users will be less likely to bounce because of slow loading pages, and as Emirodgar points out, that will send a positive signal to Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indexed images are associated with the domain that host the HTML where they are shown, so, no worries about the CDN and your domain.

Of course, it will affect SEO in a good way, cause the speed of your site will be improved and that's a [SEO ranking factor](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html).

Comment: Don't forget that a faster website will also help reduce any potential 'Pogo Sticking' (Not to be confused with Bounce Rates).  Many have argued that Pogo Sticking is also an SEO ranking factor.  Regardless, it would be something you would want to keep to a minimum.

Comment: Of course, that would help SEO but I didn't talk about Pogo Sticking cause it can be affected by other things such as content, structure, template, etc. But you are right, speed will help this ranking factor too.

Answer (score 3):

The source will be your site url and it will offer good SEO value when it has been setup correctly as the above answer said.

However make sure all the technical details and your website code or custom resources in your website is compatible with CDN to avoid any SEO problems. (This will not happen commonly but do understand there is small chance for it since it was case with one of my clients)

Also if your website is using HTTPS then make sure you use "Full HTTPS" option in CDN to avoid any insecure issues or rendering issues too.

Finally a good setup CDN does not only increase SEO but it will greatly improve the user experience and reduce the loading time of your site.